# UNPIVOT how to add incremental row numbers per ID

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following code which I am already happy with the results

```
SELECT AirlineStatementID, SegmentFrom, SegmentTo, Class, TravelDate, AirlineCode
FROM 
   (SELECT AirlineStatementID
      ,[SegmentFrom1]
      ,[SegmentFrom2]
      ,[SegmentFrom3]
      ,[SegmentFrom4]
      ,[SegmentTo1]
      ,[SegmentTo2]
      ,[SegmentTo3]
      ,[SegmentTo4]
      ,[Class1]
      ,[Class2]
      ,[Class3]
      ,[Class4]
      ,[TravelDate1] 
      ,[TravelDate2]
      ,[TravelDate3]
      ,[TravelDate4]
      ,[AirlineCode1]
      ,[AirlineCode2]
      ,[AirlineCode3]
      ,[AirlineCode4]
   FROM AirlineStatements) p
UNPIVOT
   (SegmentFrom FOR V IN (SegmentFrom1, SegmentFrom2, SegmentFrom3, SegmentFrom4)) as A
UNPIVOT   
   (SegmentTo FOR W IN (SegmentTo1, SegmentTo2, SegmentTo3, SegmentTo4)) as B
UNPIVOT   
   (Class FOR X IN (Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4)) as C
UNPIVOT   
   (TravelDate FOR Y IN (TravelDate1, TravelDate2, TravelDate3, TravelDate4)) as D
UNPIVOT   
   (AirlineCode FOR Z IN (AirlineCode1, AirlineCode2, AirlineCode3, AirlineCode4)) as E
```

The reults in the database would look like such

```
AirlineStatementID | SegmentFrom | SegmentTo | Class | TravelDate | AirlineCode
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 2010-09-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 2010-09-15 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 2010-08-25 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ
```

What I want is a row number on column so it reflects like this

```
AirlineStatementID | SegmentFrom | SegmentTo | Class | TravelDate | AirlineCode | Sequence
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 2010-09-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 1
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 2
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 3
1063 | WLG | CHC | B | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 4
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 2010-09-15 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 1
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 2
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 3
1064 | WLG | CHC | M | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 4
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 2010-08-25 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 1
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 2
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 3
1065 | WLG | CHC | Y | 1800-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NZ | 4
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following as the last column in your `SELECT`

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [AirlineStatementID] ORDER BY [TravelDate] DESC) AS [Sequence]
```

You can add additional columns in the `ORDER BY` to support any specific sorting you need

Comment: I just want to point out that, based on the sample data, this query will be non-deterministic - the `sequence` can change without the data changing because the `traveldate` is not unique.

Comment: Another question, I also notice on my query above will only work if all fields are populated if theres a null value then its showing the wrong result.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any columns in the row with null will make the data show incorrectly its looks like its repeating until it pairs with a value but if i have them all filled I get the correct results which is 4 rows per AirlineStatementID

Comment: You could try using `coalesce`, `isnull`, or a `case` statement on the columns that can have null values.