# How to generate a date to be included in UNPIVOT results without a loop?

Tags: t-sql

Say I had an example like so, where Im transposing columns into rows with UNPIVOT.

```
DECLARE  @pvt AS TABLE  (VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int, Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);

INSERT INTO @pvt (VendorId,Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4,Emp5) VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt (VendorId,Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4,Emp5) VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO @pvt (VendorId,Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4,Emp5) VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt (VendorId,Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4,Emp5) VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO @pvt (VendorId,Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4,Emp5) VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);

--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM @pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

Which produces results like this

```
   VendorID     Employee    Orders
    1           Emp1            4
    1           Emp2            3
    1           Emp3            5
    1           Emp4            4
    1           Emp5            4
    2           Emp1            4
    2           Emp2            1
    2           Emp3            5
    2           Emp4            5
    2           Emp5            5
    3           Emp1            4
    3           Emp2            3
    3           Emp3            5
    3           Emp4            4
    3           Emp5            4
```

However, I want to include an "incremental date like so that it repeats in a group for each Vendor and the results would be like this

```
VendorID    Employee    Orders      OrderDate
1           Emp1            4       01/01/2014
1           Emp2            3       02/01/2014
1           Emp3            5       03/01/2014
1           Emp4            4       04/01/2014
1           Emp5            4       05/01/2014
2           Emp1            4       ..
2           Emp2            1
2           Emp3            5
2           Emp4            5
2           Emp5            5
3           Emp1            4
3           Emp2            3
3           Emp3            5
3           Emp4            4
3           Emp5            4
```

The kicker is that I want to try to do this without resorting to a loop since the transposed results are going to be about 100K records.  Is there a way to generate that date field like that without looping over the results?

[edit]
I think, but not sure yet, that **[this]**[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611980/unpivot-how-to-add-incremental-row-numbers-per-id) post might help, using ROW NUMBER

Comment: What Is the starting date and when do you reset the increment? On order, on employe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Dateadd(DAY, row_number() over( partition by VendorId Order by Employee), @stardate)
```

According to your example you can partition by vendorId and order by Employee. But you can change just like a regular order by.